# config.status: error: cannot find input file: `po/Makefile.in.in'

Tags: configure, autotools, automake, po

I hit this error message while trying to build **gnote** using GNU Autotools.

I had first run:

```
$ git clean -xf    # to clean the tree of untracked files, then
$ autoreconf       # to create the script named `configure`, and finally 
$ ./configure      # to check my system, and create Makefiles from their templates
```

---

Neither `po/Makefile.in.in` nor `po/Makefile.in` exist in the source tree that I downloaded.

Yet `configure` needs to make this `po/Makefile`, as called for in the root `Makefile.am` in this line:

```
SUBDIRS = data src po help
```

Where do I get, or how do I make, `po/Makefile.in.in`?

Answer (score 4):

Like all Gnome related packages, `gnote` uses many steps of buildsystem setup beyond just running `autoreconf`.

The `autogen.sh` script `gnote` comes with should run all the required steps to set up the buildsystem.

As usual, run the `autogen.sh` script with the `--help` parameter if you want to call `configure` separately.

Answer (score 1):

`po/Makefile.in.in` is created by running `intltoolize` from the intltool package.  It needs to be run from the project tree's root directory.

---

There isn't much documentation on `intltoolize` that I could find except for the brief man page, but it's source code says that that it's a fork of an older utility called `libtoolize`, and it's a relatively short script.

(BTW, if you don't already have `intltoolize` installed, you can figure out which package installs it, with this:  `sudo apt-file find intltoolize`.)

---

`*.in` files are templates used by AutoMake to create a Makefile.

`.in.in` is a soft link to `/usr/share/intltool/Makefile.in.in`.